# Not able to use mysql in google app engine - Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named _mysql. I am using cloudSQL

Tags: python, mysql, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am using googleAppEngineLauncher to try mysql connection.

It gives the log

```
 File "/Users/kakshilshah/Desktop/hope/skeduleBackend/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/kakshilshah/Desktop/hope/skeduleBackend/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 17, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named _mysql
```

I have done `pip install MySQL-python`

Even commands like `python manage.py dbshell` works, and connects me to the cloudsql backend.

I can access all the tables there.

But, running it gives the same error.

I have mysql 5.6 installed.

Adding the following to app.yaml

```
- name: MySQLdb
  version: "latest"
```

also does not help, because I checked the libraries directory and there was no mysqldb.

My settings -

```
import os

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': '173.194.xxx.xxx',
            'NAME': 'my_database',
            'USER': 'root',
            'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxxxx',
    }
}
```

Stuck here, please help.

Comment: Same here, are you on Mac?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot have MySQL-python while uploading. Remove that and then upload.

Just the YAML file's

```
- name: MySQLdb
  version: "latest"
```

Will do, if you add both, it causes a clash.

It runs locally because it does not consider the YAML's sqldb connector.

Hope this helps!